# for language L={a^n b^m c^l d^k | n==l,m==k} is correct or not?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

**Is it correct or not?**

Is this PDA **NPDA** or **DPDA**? I'm confused.

Someone please answer me.

**Here I created PDA for the language**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This question is better suited to [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)